# yii set selected dropdownlist from other dropdownlist

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii

i have 4 dropdownlist, 1 dropdownlist as master to control 3 dropdownlist other, this my sample code for master dropdownlist.

```
<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($truck,'Truck'); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('idt',$truck->idt,CHtml::listData(Truck::model()->findAll(),'idt','number'),
        array(
            'value'=>'1',
            'ajax' => array(
                'type'=>'POST', 
                'url'=>CController::createUrl('FindTruck'),             
                'data'=>array('idt'=>'js:this.value'),
                'dataType'=>'html',

            ))); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <?php echo $form->labelEx($employee,'Driver'); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('driver','$variable',CHtml::listData(Employe::model()->findAll(),'ide','name')); ?>
    </div>
```

This My js setDriver

```
function setDriver(name,value){
    document.getElementById(name).value = value
}
```

and this my controller

```
public function actionFindTruck() {
   echo "<script>setDriver('driver',3);</script>"; // test satatic data
}
```

the question what code must i write on controller (ActionFindTruck) to change value of $variable above, so if i change Truck, the Driver will be change selected.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I did it, you should be able to change the values to your environment:

```
public function actionUpdateDropdown()
{   
    // ajax function to retrieve categories by country:
    $lang_id = (!empty($_POST['feature']['language_id'])) ? $_POST['feature']['language_id'] : DEFAULT_LANG_ID;

    $data = category::model()->findAll('language_id=:parent_id', 
                  array(':parent_id'=>(int) $lang_id));

    $data = CHtml::listData($data,'id','name');
    if (!empty($data)) { echo '<option value="">Select Category...</option>'; }
    foreach($data as $value=>$name) {
        echo CHtml::tag('option',
            array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($name),true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks lgd, this is just show dropdown list for category from selected language, not selected of a category, and show new content on category dropdownlist ?, on my code, the content not will change, and not will be reload, just selected a driver if the truck selected, so on controller just get what IDDriver from an IDTruck by default. have you idea for this ?

Comment: In that case you can simply pass back some javascript and specify the jquery/ajax dataType attribute to "html" or "script". You can return the full function or call to a function, so your controller return code would look like: `echo '<script>syncDriver('. $truck_id .');</script>'` where you get $truck_id from your controller function and "syncDriver" is a pre-loaded javascript function. You can abstract a function to update various drop-downs.

Comment: hi lgd, i'm a newbiew :), could you write simple code, ex if on truck i select idt=2 and the controller i make query driver with idt=2,the ex iddriver=5, so dropdownlist at Driver will selected at value=5. thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Hi lgd, i have try use javascipt with success, but when i parse from controller with echo "<script>setDriver('driver',3);</script>"; this code not work

Comment: in the `'ajax'=>array()` add `'dataType'=>'html'`

Comment: thank for your response lgd, i has added code your type, but not success, my code has update like your guide on above.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice discussion of creating dependent drop downs at this URL:

[Creating a dependent dropdown](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/24/)